# smartgit compare remote repository with local repository before pull or push

Tags: windows, git, smartgit

I'm very new to using git so I'm probably just missing something simple here.  I have a remote repository (Bonobo, windows git) and a local repository.  There is only 1 branch called master.  I'm only working with 1 other developer, Bob.

Let's start with both Bob and I have smartgit (Windows client) and we have a test.txt file in our repos and in the remote origin repo.  The file is exactly the same.

Bob edits his local test file with "superduper", commits locally, and pushes.

I hit refresh, nothing changes, hm.. I wait a minute or two and a green arrow shows up.  OK great there is a change!

Now I view the log (right click on repo), no changes, no comments? I right click the rep and hit refresh, nothing. I log directly into the remote origin, yep, there are the changes "superduper".  I wait around for 10 minutes, my Journal area updates with the log of his commit changes "superduper" and can even see the actual change in the file compare view.  Great, it's all working!  But there seems to be a lot of waiting.

So, my 2 questions are:

1 - How can I make the little green arrow show up faster so I know the repo changed (or by manually forcing a check)

2 - How can I make the Journal update faster (or manually force) once I have the green arrow.  Sitting around for 10 minutes for the Journal to update so I can see the changed w/o pulling and overwriting seems like a long time.

Thank you very much for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for both questions is pull. It will pull all new changes from remote to your local repository. Refresh looks only for changes made locally.

Since you are new to git, I think it is worth mentioning that pull comes in two forms: pull and fetch. Fetch looks for any new commits on the remote and brings them to your local repository, but it does not change your HEAD. Pull does two things: 1. Fetch, 2. look whether there are new commits in your current branch. If there are, it tries to incorporate those new commits with your local commits either with merge or with rebase. If you did not do any local commits, it just fast-forwards your current HEAD to the latest state came from the remote.

Note that green arrow occurs only when you did fetch (either manually or in background), it shows that there are new commits that you can pull.